# Creating multiple clients with 3 threads

Tags: multithreading, mqtt, paho

I remarked that for every new client created there is 3 other threads created with ( one for publish, one for reconect, and one for messagearrived). So when i am creating 100 clients i am getting a lots of threads. I tried to reuse the same callback for all the clients but didn't work.

Is there any way to have multiple clients running on 3-5 threads only??

Thanks

---

i am using paho java library.

My code is something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
client[i]=new MqttClient(ip,i,persistence);
client[i].setCallback(callback);
}
```

//persistence & callback are static

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need 100s of clients from a single application?

Comment: To Perform some tests/simulation